# What's the meaning of 'many firsts?'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Today's headline on [an Indian news channel:](http://www.ndtv.com/india-news/on-a-visit-of-many-firsts-japanese-pm-abe-to-land-in-gujarat-today-10-points-1749549)

> On ***A Visit Of Many Firsts,*** Japanese PM Abe To Arrive In Gujarat Today: 10 Facts

Japanese Prime Minister is visiting Gujarat, India.

What's 'many firsts' here?

Answer (score 17):

*First* in this context is a shortened, more informal way of saying "the first occurrence  of an event". By extension, *many firsts* is the first occurrence of multiple, distinct events. Through the link provided it seems like the *firsts* referred to are the beginning of work of India's first high speed rail project, the "first-of-its-kind roadshow" of the two leaders, and presumably other events which have not been mentioned in this particular article.

The phrase *many firsts* or *a number of firsts* is one that comes up occasionally, and tends to denote positive progress. In this example, it is saying that the Japanese Prime Minister is starting things with the Indian government that have not been done before, implying positive growth in the relations between Japan and India.